# How does GO template association work?

Tags: go

I am reading GO's text/template doc and confused by these following description.

https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template

> Each template is named by a string specified when it is created. Also, each template is associated with zero or more other templates that it may invoke by name; such associations are transitive and form a name space of templates.

.

> By construction, a template may reside in only one association. If it's necessary to have a template addressable from multiple associations, the template definition must be parsed multiple times to create distinct *Template values, or must be copied with the Clone or AddParseTree method.

How can template association be transitive but then it can only reside in one association? Some examples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Transitivity is just: If template A knows B and B knows C then A knows C as well (and can call C). This "x knows y" relation is established by parsing: EIther because there are `{{define}}` and `{{block}}` statements in the template or because you parse multiple files at once, e.g. via ParseFiles. Association is established by parsing templates together. Put roughly: "parsed-together" templates may call each one. Actually this is just transitiv, not each every one.

Comment: There is no contradiction in "each template is in just one association" and "association is transitive". Each time you add new templates to the association (by calling Parse with a definition with {{define}} or {{block}}) you enlarge the association in a transitive way: What you add is reachable from every already associated.